# How to merge two DEM (Digital Elevation Model ) files using r?

Tags: r

I have two .hgt files, and I would like to join them.

**Reading files**

```
library(raster)

h1=raster("E:/FILES/S12E043.hgt")

h2=raster("E:/FILES/S13E043.hgt")
```

How to merge them?

Comment: Without knowing anything about these files or your code or how you want to merge them, all anyone can really do is guess. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Comment: @camille : I modifed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `raster` package to merge them like

```
library(raster)

m = mosaic(h1, h2, fun=mean)
```

m is the merged raster.